# self signed certificate for azure ad registered applications

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

Hi I have a daemon application which will access Azure AD graph API.
I am trying to have certificate based authentication,Hence first creatinga self signed certificate.
I have followed this article
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/resources/samples/active-directory-dotnet-daemon-certificate-credential/

I am using windows 10 machine.

When I try to modify the manifest file of registered application of Azure AD I get below error

*Failed to update application graphapi2. Error details: KeyValue cannot be null or empty Request ID: fea0789a-b8fd-4001-83c4-f74d67fb9812, Timestamp: 12/13/2018 11:56:08*

Has any one faced this issue?How will I be able to create self signed certificate to azure ad registered applications.

Comment: Are you able to successfully upload the cert using the Credentials page UI in the App registrations (Preview) experience?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working by following this link :-github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnetcore-daemon-v2 . While exporting the key choose the option ->Do not export private key->Base 64 encoded option.Later I uploaded the certificated in the app registrations preview and it works!! :)

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be happening in the Azure Portal when using the "App registrations (preview)" rather than the normal "App registrations". If you try "App registrations" and edit the manifest there and add your KeyCredentials it seems to work fine.

Comment: I got this working , in azure app registration preview following above link and mentioned the solution above.